# MonoTouch app stopped debugging in IPhone Simulator

Tags: ios, xcode, xamarin.ios, monodevelop, xamarin

I have an app thats been debugging fine in the simulator for months and suddenly stopped.  I just get the "waiting for debugger to connect" then it cancels on my end.  I have reinstalled xCode to no avail.  I have also confirmed other monotouch apps work. I've tried cleaning and re-building. I've reset the settings in the simulator.  Build SDK is set to default and Linker set to "Don't Link".  even though the app does not get copied to the simulator there is an entry for the app in settings and debug is enabled.  I am using Monocross in this app but I dont think that has anything to do with it since the Android version runs fine in its emulator.  Any help will be greatly appreciated! Below is my version info

```
MonoDevelop 3.0.5
Installation UUID: ceba78be-070b-46a7-9bfd-508842217b52
Runtime:
    Mono 2.10.9 (tarball)
    GTK 2.24.10
    GTK# (2.12.0.0)
    Package version: 210090011
Mono for Android: 4.2.7 (Evaluation)
Android SDK: /Users/darrell/Library/Developer/Xamarin/android-sdk-mac_x86
    Supported Android versions:
        2.1 (API level 7)
        2.2 (API level 8)
        2.3 (API level 10)
        3.1 (API level 12)
        4.0 (API level 14)
Java SDK: /usr
Apple Developer Tools:
     Xcode 4.5.2 (1847)
     Build 4G2008a
Monotouch: 6.0.6 (Evaluation)
Build information:
    Release ID: 30005000
    Git revision: e159cf083bd327933166819d94245298898d6e3d
    Build date: 2012-10-24 16:43:06+0000
    Xamarin addins: eea2ed91ae8dd242b281d5ec8f6c2fbc63b4cd3d
Operating System:
    Mac OS X 10.8.2
    Darwin MacBook-Air.local 12.2.0 Darwin Kernel Version 12.2.0
        Sat Aug 25 00:48:52 PDT 2012
        root:xnu-2050.18.24~1/RELEASE_X86_64 x86_64
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That's likely a configuration issue, i.e. unrelated to the versions of the software you're using. E.g. make sure the version of the simulator you run match our application version (e.g. using iOS 5.1 simulator with an app that requires iOS 6.0).

> even though the app does not get copied to the simulator there is an entry for the app in settings and debug is enabled.

If you see this in the settings that's because the app is present on the simulator. How do you know it does **not** get copied ?

Anyway since it means the app is present there's a few things you can try:

1. Start the application from the simulator itself (without using MonoDevelop);
2. Start the application with Run (from MonoDevelop) not Debug;

If either works then try to reset your simulator. From the simulator, use the **iOS Simulator** menu and select **Reset Content and Settings**.

Note that this will remove everything (data and other apps) from the simulator.

Comment: 1. no icon on simulator to run directly. 2. tried that but didnt work.  but I did just copied all of the files to a new project and now its back working. What could have been the culprit...for some reason Im guessing a faulty info.plst. Leading up to my problems the files was acting quirky and sometimes wouldnt load for me to edit